# How to extract marker data points from a line plotted with markevery argument?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get the data coordinates of line markers drawn with a help of [`markevery`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html) option. My attempt at the code below shows that the retrieved (x,y) data contains all original data values and the argument is ignored:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

line, = plt.plot(np.arange(100)**2, marker='o', markevery=(0, 0.1))

x, y = line.get_data()
assert len(x) != 100
```

Note the value of `markevery` argument—advanced indexing on the data in this case is not applicable as an alternative.

Of course, I can successfully use private  utility method [`lines._mark_every_path()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/61085e1b5bd335d51cdc9959426df6eecd05a091/lib/matplotlib/lines.py#L118) to solve the problem I deal with. But is there any more, let's say, "correct" way to do that?

Comment: Independent of what `markevery` is set to, the line itself has (and should of course have) the same number of points. I do not understand the problem of using `_mark_every_path()`.

Comment: Well, just after posting the question I realized the limited purpose (in the context of the problem) of `get_data()`method, a method with such self-explanatory name. So, I find your clarification on this part in the answer you've been given to be useful. In the absence of other ways without touching Matplotlib internals, the mentioned solution suits me fine for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `markevery` option allows to subsample the marked datapoints on a line. Which points are marked or not is only determined at the moment the line is drawn. There is hence no attribute of the line that would store the data of the shown points, because they might change all the time, depending on the size and limits of the plot.

The solution is indeed to replicate the drawing behaviour of the line to access the coordinates of the marked points, using `_mark_every_path`.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import lines

line, = plt.plot(np.arange(100)**2, marker='o', markevery=(0, 0.1))

tpath, affine = line._get_transformed_path().get_transformed_points_and_affine()
p = lines._mark_every_path(line.get_markevery(), 
                      tpath, affine, line.axes.transAxes)

print(len(p.vertices)) # prints 10
print(p.vertices)      # print array of points, shape (10,2)
plt.show()
```